# Background Url problem in Safari only

Tags: css, url, background

I have the following class

```
div.application {
background: url(http:/appimages/background.gif) #fff bottom left repeat-x;
height: 20px;
line-height: 10px;
width:80px;
display: block;
text-align:center;
Font-weight:200; 
font-size: 10pt;
 padding:5px;
}
```

I use this to build a button like navigation that looks three dimensional.

in all browsers I tested, Chrome, Firefox, IE and different versions this works fine, except for Safari.  The image does not appear.

Comment: `http:/appimages/background.gif` does not make sense as a URL. Which URL do you mean, and does it work when you call it directly?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a "/" in the image url.

Change `http:/appimages/background.gif` to `http://appimages/background.gif` and it should work.

The color value (#fff) should also be the first property set in the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be two errors in your declaration, the order is wrong and the url is to the image is some sort of mix between absolute and relative.

background: url(http:/appimages/background.gif) #fff bottom left repeat-x;

Should probably be

```
background: #fff url(appimages/background.gif) repeat-x scroll left bottom;
```

or if the images is really on another server

```
background: #fff url(http://www.yourdomain.com/appimages/background.gif) repeat-x scroll left bottom;
```

Scroll is default and can be omitted..